# Display location based currency identifiers in text field placeholder

Tags: xcode, swift

Basically within my app I have two text fields for pound and pence value inputs. I am currently working on making my app localised and I have ran into an issue. My textfields have the placeholders 'Pounds' and 'Pence' and I need them to display placeholders for the currency and sub-currency based on the users location such as 'Dollars' and 'Cents' for the US.

I have no idea how to do this in a way that would be efficient and I was hoping for some suggestions as to how I could go about this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the local currency by using NSLocale:

```
var locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
var currencyCode: (AnyObject!) = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode)
locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode, value: code) // "British Pound"
```

However, it seems that you may not be satisifed with the official name and I am not aware of a way to get Pence or Cents so you can also create your own list using locale identifiers:

```
struct LocalCurrency {
    static func wholeName(forLocale locale: NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()) -> String {
        var identifier : String = locale.localeIdentifier
        switch(identifier) {
            case "en_UK":
                return "Pounds"
            case "en_US":
                return "Dollar"
            default:
                return ""
        }
    }
}
LocalCurrency.wholeName() // "Pounds"
```

You can create a similar method for partial currencies and you will have to add all locales you want to support manually, but at least the device will tell you what the current Locale is.

**Update:**

You can also get the currency symbol:

```
locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: code) // £
```

Or you can use an NSNumberFormatter to format currency for you:

```
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.stringFromNumber(1.23) // £1.23
```

Perhaps you can use one of those to come up with a new format for how you want to display it without creating a manual list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll have to consider whether I want to reduce the number of countries my app will support and use the manual method you suggested, or just come up with different wording for the placeholders that make sense with other currencies.

Comment: @user3746428, sure. I also update my answer with two other possibilities. Potentially you could just use the currency symbol with a decimal point to separate out the "pounds" from "pence"

Comment: Yeah, using the symbol is definitely a more simple solution. It isn't as visually appealing and it won't be perfect for currencies like the Euro where the symbol is after the value, but it might be my best solution. Either way, I'll end up using one of your suggestions so thanks!